# How can partial eta squared be 5% and yet SPSS says 0.045?

Tags: anova, spss

The partial eta squared indicates that gender explains 5% of the variance in drugs and ethnicity explains 6% of the variance in drugs. These are small effect sizes.
I am not sure I understand this because when I look at the ANOVA table produced by SPSS it says that the Partial ETA squared for gender is .045 and for ethnicity is .060.

Are these figures just rounded up and moved over a few decimal places?

Answer (score 2):

I think that maybe going from 4.5% to 5% was rounding.  Seems that the numbers are rounded to the nearest 1%.   The other difference 0.045 and 0.06 compared to 5% and 6% is just the conversion from a numerical proportion to a percentage.  This is really not a statistical question even though it may involve interpreting output from an ANOVA analysis.